# How to print html tags

Tags: php, html, tags

I want to create a html list item with php for a webpage with dynamic content by printing the tags. I want to do something like this

```
<?php
...
...
print(<li>$Row['Name']</li>);
...
...
?>
```

but it doesnt work. How can I do that ?? Thanks for your help.

Comment: search the title on google

Comment: you want data from database??

Comment: echo "<li>" . $Row['Name'] . "</li>";

Comment: Yes I get the data from the database  and want to display it as a list Item

Comment: Where is your database query???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the page's file name must have `.php` extension, as well as having PHP being enabled on your web server.

Second, add something along the lines of this in to your page:

```
<?php
# ...
print("<li>".$Row['Name']."</li>");
# ...
?>
```

Note: I don't know what else content you have but you can do it yourself by adding quotes around html tags carefully as I did in my example.

Comment: I did but I have to wait for 2 minutes to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
print "<li>$Row['Name']</li>";
```

If you mean that you want to see the tags on the browser page instead of them being actual, functioning tags, then:

```
print htmlspecialchars("<li>$Row['Name']</li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:
echo "<li>$Row['Name']</li>";
```